# SSIS DataViewer configuration of Parent Child environment

Tags: ssis, parent-child

within my SSIS project I created master layer (see picture) that refers to different child packages.

Within those packages I have DataViewer for printing summary table.

Issue I am having is that although the execution of child packages goes without any problems both from parent and child level, the DataViewer table appears only when I'm executing child package. From the master level I am able to execute the child package but the summary table doesn't appear. How to fix that?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Add some more detail ..

Comment: Let's put it that way. From Master layer I want SSIS to display the table from Layer 1. But from the Master level everything execute without problems but the table doesn't appear. It only appears when I'm executing the Child package. Hope it helps, I don't know how to explain that in more details, normally it should work but probably I'm missing something?

Comment: Sorry, still no idea what you're trying to describe.   Question is not clear.

Comment: Question is very clear, I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution? (took me forever to figure out that it works when I execute the child alone... and now it sucks that I don't find a solution)

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found the solution yet. No one has a clue.